# Is there any way to limit the size of flow table in Open vSwitch and to verify that it is working?

Tags: overflow, sdn

I have used the following instruction to restrict the flow table 0 to 5 entries only:

$ sudo ovs-vsctl  --  --id=@ft  create  Flow_Table flow_limit=5 overflow_policy=refuse -- set Bridge s1 flow_tables=0=@ft

When i dump flows, it applies the limit 5 to flow table 0 as follows:

sudo ovs-ofctl dump-tables s1
OFPST_TABLE reply (xid=0x2):
table 0 ("classifier"):
active=1, lookup=26, matched=0
**max_entries=5**

But when i ping from h1 to h2, it keep storing the ping more than 5 as follows

Comment: Try using 1 rule only. Let's see if it works. I know that OVS has some hidden rules stored (cannot remember the purpose for all of them). If you have 5 rules as max then why wouln't it store the flows for two hosts? Try to have 6 or 10 hots and try pinging with max 4 rules, let's say. and check if it works. Print the rules indeed because there is a chance the controller could be sending a packet out directly instead of storing the rule.

Answer (score 0):

A flow entry is defined as a unique tuple.

There is only one entry, h1 to h2. Although there are multiple pings, the same flow entry is receiving packets, which is why it says, "active=1".

If you were to pingall, the response would read, "active=2":

- h1 to h2
- h2 to h1